# PDO class wrapper

Tags: php, pdo

I'm writing one custom class for PDO connection.

I want these advantages:

- Protect credentials: user, password ...
- Facilitate maintenance: facing future password changes for example
- Facilitate connection: `$pdo=new MyPDO();`
- Provide my class with all the PDO functionalities

I write my class as you can see here:

For protecting credentials I saved them into an `ini` file:

```
<?php return; ?>
; credentials
host=localhost
user=myUser
pass="my/very/secure/password.../UqMsN[)VPn&gunmv3KzE?3Q&Qw/..."
dbname=myDataBase
```

#### The class

```
class MyPDO extends PDO
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $iniData = parse_ini_file("//home/.credentials/db.php.ini");
        $host=$iniData["host"];
        $dbname=$iniData["dbname"];
        $user=$iniData["user"];
        $pass=$iniData["pass"];
        $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname";


        $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => FALSE, 
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE, 
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"
        );

        try {
                parent::__construct($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            error_log($this->error = $e->getMessage(),0);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

---

#### Usage example

```
include_once('MyPDO.php');
$pdo=new MyPDO();
/*Use any PDO method*/

$pdo->query(...);
$pdo->prepare(...);
$pdo->execute(...);
```

Comment: So you actually *exposed* your credentials to anyone who wold have a whim of navigating to .credentials/db.php.ini

Comment: @YourCommonSense thaks for your comment. The credentials are not exposed. 1º. The folder is out of `public_html`, then, non navigation possible (i'm using shared hosting). 2º. The first line: `<?php return; ?>`  prevents to show the file content in case of access to fila via browser. I think the info is protected so.

Answer (score 2):

There are several areas for improvement.

- First of all, it violates the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). I am guilty for doing it too, so I cannot blame you too much but if you want your code to follow the best practices, it's better to make your class not extend PDO but either

  - make a PDO instance a property of your class publicly accessible through a property or a method.
  - or - if you want to have a class with PDO's functionality but a different constructor, you have to re-create in your class all the functionality supported by PDO. Although sounds too laborious, it is not that hard as it seems but it pays back in the future.
- Next, error reporting for the connection is rather inflexible. An exception is a precious thing that can be handled in many different ways, logging included. So I would rather re-throw a new exception, like

  ```
  try {
      parent::__construct($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
  } catch (PDOException $e) {
      throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
  }
  ```

  so it won't expose the connection credentials in the stack trace but still it can be caught elsewhere or simply logged if a corresponding PHP configuration directive says so.
- Connection encoding is better to be set in the DSN, as it's going to be more generic and supported by all drivers.
- reading the configuration right in the class violates the [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). I would make this class to accept an array of parameters, as to where these parameters are taken from - an `.ini`, `.yml` or `.env` file - is a distinct matter.
- "Facilitate maintenance" option is somewhat defeated by the hardcoding of the configuration file name. What if you want to change it in the future as well? A typical web application has dozens of configuration options, it's just impractical to put them in different files whose names are hardcoded in different modules. To make a maintainable application it's better to have a distinct module for configuration that will supply different options to all other modules.
- And all the hassle related to protecting the configuration should be delegated elsewhere. After all, database credentials are not only settings that have to be protected - there are admin email, salt, API keys, etc.
- protecting an ini file adding .php as one of its extensions is too risky. It would work merely by accident (It would work only under Apache web-server if a certain configuration option is set). Why not to name it straight `settings.php` and thus make sure it will be always interpreted as PHP as long as it is called through a web-server with PHP support?
- I would also add a possibility to add/override the PDO options

So I would make your class

```
class DB
{
    protected $connection;
    public function __construct($config)
    {
        $dsn = "mysql:host=$config[host];dbname=$config[dbname];charset=$config[charset]";

        $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => FALSE,
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => FALSE,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        );
        if (isset($config['options'])) {
            $options = array_merge($options, $config['options']);
        }

        try {
            $this->connection = new \PDO ($dsn, $config['user'], $config['pass'], $options);
        } catch (\PDOException $e) {
            throw new \PDOException($e->getMessage(), (int)$e->getCode());
        }
    }
    public function conn() {
        return $this->connection;
    }
}
```

used as

```
$db = new DB($config);
$stmt = $db->conn()->query('SELECT * FROM users');
```